# Have an issue with get access token for Sony application

Tags: authentication, sony

HI I am trying to get access token for Sony application according to https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/authentication/ 
I have made first request like 
https://platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com/oauth/2/authorize?client_id=CLIENT_ID&scope=lifelog.profile.read+lifelog.activities.read+lifelog.locations.read

And got a response like 
go.sap.com/index.html?code=O6xgtyUfk90A1ispqeXFmNCdX0Y#

then I have made POST request to 
platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com/oauth/2/token

with header Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
and body like 
client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=authorization_code&code=O6xgtyUfk90A1ispqeXFmNCdX0Y#

But got 400 code in response and 
{
"title": "Client Not Found",
"message": "The specified client was not found. There may be a problem with the application you're using."
}
in the body. Have anybody what I did wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the super late reply to this question, but unfortunately due to business decisions the Lifelog API has been completely shut down at this point. We apologize for any inconvenience caused.